# There exists a prime ideal not containing non-nilpotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I've been trying to solve the following problem.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $a \in A$ a non-nilpotent element, i.e., $a^m \neq 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove there exists a prime ideal that fails to contain $a$.

I've been trying to somehow define a partial order on the prime ideals of $A$ to apply Zorn's lemma and proves the existence of such a prime ideal, but I am not sure this approach would work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you heard about the nilradical?

Comment: Consider the set of *all* ideals that do not contain the set $\{a^m\mid m\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$. Show it satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn’s Lemma, and then show that a maximal element in that set is in fact a prime ideal.

Comment: I have not heard about nilradical.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin how do I know the set of all ideals that do not contain $a^m$ for all $m$ is not empty (not considering the $0$ ideal)?

Comment: @Peter: Because $(0)$ is one of them... Why do you not want to consider that ideal? It’s a perfectly fine ideal. It will even be prime in some rings. Are you a zeroist, discriminating against the zero ideal? ;-)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I got it now. You are right: $(0)$ is an ideal ideal.

Comment: @Peter: I said “do not contain”, but it should be “that are disjoint from”... the ideals shouldn’t contain any of the elements in the set.

Comment: Ok, anyway I understood the idea behind the words.

Comment: @Peter Hi: at the suggested duplicate, the last paragraphs outline a solution to exactly this. Happy to help if you have questions.